# Redirect user to a directory using mod_rewrite - Simple question

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to do so if the user going to this url:

http://www.abc.com/

it will redirect him to

http://www.abc.com/minisite/

or, if he's going to tihs url:

http://www.abc.com/dir/something.php

it will redirect him to:

http://www.abc.com/minisite/dir/something.php

I'm trying to do this in Mod_Rewrite... Here is what I've wrriten so far:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /minisite/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /minisite/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It's working, but the problem is that if im going to a non exist page, it do 500 instead of 404..

Any ideas on how to fix that and/or improve my rules?

Thanks and sorry for English (it'd be great if you'll edit this question so the grammer will be correct and more understandable, thanks).

Comment: In addition to the .htaccess in docroot, do you have an .htaccess in the minisite directory?

Comment: Also, you only need the [QSA] flag if you're setting query string variables (i.e. you have a question mark) in the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is as simple as

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !minisite
RewriteRule (.*) minisite/$1 [L]
```

This will map anything coming in (except well-formed minisite URLs) to the minisite directory.